# Is J.A.R.V.I.S. the Vision?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

So... me and my friend have been arguing ever since Avengers: Age of Ultron was released.  He thinks that Vision is literally just Jarvis in a new body. But I disagree. I think that Vision is an entirely new entity.
...let me walk through this

So Ultron tries to make a perfect synthetic body for himself and uploads a good bit of himself into the body... then Tony and Bruce get ahold of it and try to upload Jarvis into it (they start to but it's ruined by Quicksilver). Then Thor (after seeing  visions of the future and the world being destroyed by the mind stone) brings Vision to life with an electric hammer bash.

The Vision then wakes up and is confused about where he is.
After a brief fight scene he is changing his appearance...and talking.

From the [Transcripts Wiki](https://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron):

> Steve Rogers: Why does your "vision" sound like JARVIS?
>   Tony Stark: We... we reconfigured JARVIS' matrix to create something new.
>   Steve Rogers: I think I've had my fill of new.
>   Vision: You think I'm a child of Ultron?
>   Steve Rogers: You're not?
>   Vision: I'm not Ultron. I'm not JARVIS. I am... I am.

So... in that last line Vision stated that he is NOT Jarvis. Yet my friend still states that Jarvis is the Vision. And I have argued back as well as I can but he won't budge. But I feel that fact is...that Vision (although he has some ofJarvis that he was made up of) is an new entity and is not "controlled" by Jarvis (like the way Jarvis can control the Iron Man suits).

This is a very raging argument and im slowly being beat down by a lot of nieve people agreeing with him. And I would appreciate a lot of feedback on the matter below. So is Jarvis the Vision?

Comment: Not answering the question, but... if you've already pointed out the part where he says "I'm not Jarvis" and your friend still won't back down... maybe it's not worthwhile to keep arguing. Which is more important, your friendship or you being right?

Answer (score 29):

**tl;dr:** JARVIS is not The Vision. JARVIS is *one part of* The Vision.

---

The Vision is a unique entity that was formed by the merging of quite a few distinct elements:

- Ultron's base "operating system"
- The power of the Mind Stone
- The "protocols" (personality?) of JARVIS.
- Random Thor Magic

Most of The Vision is actually based on Ultron. Remember that Ultron spent a long time uploading himself into the body that he built. He intended for it to be his body, when it was completed, and had poured a lot of his own programming into the body.

On top of that, Ultron has fused the Mind Stone onto the body, knowing how powerful it was. Ultron knew that part of the Mind Stone's power was used to create his own programming, but by fusing it directly onto the new body, he was making something "better" than his current form. Ultron must have known that this would somehow unlock the full potential of the Mind Stone, which is why he wanted it transfer himself into that body.

Later, Stark and Banner took recovered bits of JARVIS's programming, and uploaded them into the partially-completed body. The goal here was to make the thing that Stark wanted all along -- as smart and Ultron but with JARVIS's sense of purpose and "good behavior" built in.

Finally, The Vision was only completed when Thor charged it with Mjolnir. It's kept somewhat vague in the movie just how much this affected the final outcome. But, note that Quicksilver had *unplugged* the coffin from all of Stark's equipment before it had finished whatever it was doing, and Thor's lightning completed that process.

The Vision, therefore, is an amalgam of all of those elements together, which makes him a separate, sentient being -- even more than a simple AI, and certainly way beyond what JARVIS was.

Comment: I believe "Random Thor Magic" is the technical term.